# Angular submits records but cannot display server response

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular6. I used the code below to submit records to database. It works fine, but cannot display sever response via json call. I want it to display server response message **success** after submission. In the AngularJS I can easily do it with successful callback but in the Angular6 I can't.

At app.component.ts I have also tried

```
this.cars = res[0].message;
```

or

```
this.cars = res[0]['message'];
```

Here is the **store.php**

```php
<?php
// parameters goes here
// after submission display message below

$car = [
      'message' => 'success'
    ];
echo json_encode($car);

?>
```

here is the app.component.ts

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Car } from './car';
import { CarService } from './car.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  //cars: Car[];

cars: Car;
  error = '';
  success = '';

 car = new Car('', 0);

//declare loading image for form submission
 public showloader: boolean = false;

  constructor(private carService: CarService) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCars();
  }

  getCars(): void {
    this.carService.getAll().subscribe(
      (res: Car[]) => {
        this.cars = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    );
  }

public regCar(r) {
          this.resetErrors();
          this.carService.store(this.car)
            .subscribe(
              res => {
                alert(res);

                if (res.message === 'success') { // or this.cars['message']
                    // Inform the user
                    this.success = 'Created successfully';
                }

                // Reset the form
                r.reset();
              },
              err => this.error = err
            );
    }
```

here is car.service.ts

```js
store(car: Car): Observable<Car[]> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, { data: car })
      .pipe(map((res) => {
          //this.cars.push(res['data']);

          this.cars =res['data'];

          return this.cars;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

here is car.ts

```
export class Car {
  constructor(
    model: string,
    price: number,
    id?:   number) {}
}
```

Comment: `this.cars = res['data'];` -> your store.php endpoint isn't returning any `data` value. You probably need `this.cars = res.message` for this code to work, but your service method's signature doesn't make much sense then. Should be `Observable<string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand by quickly looking at the php json_encode() method it will change your array ['message' => 'success] in to {message : 'success'}. So in order to access the value part of the json object now, all you need to do is to access the response key/value like so, res.message or if you save your res into your this.cars variable you can do this.cars.message or this.cars['message'].

**app.component.ts**

```
public regCar(r) {
          this.resetErrors();
          this.carService.store(this.car)
            .subscribe(
              res => {
                alert(res);

                if (res.message === 'success') { // or this.cars['message']
                    // Inform the user
                    this.success = 'Created successfully';
                }

                // Reset the form
                r.reset();
              },
              err => this.error = err
            );
    }
```

**car.service.ts**

```
public store(car: Car): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store.php`, { data: car })
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError))
      );
}
```

Comment: after adding your code to my app, am having error message does not exist on type string and that cars does not exist on CarServices. I have updated my entire my entire code for app.component.ts to reflect your modifications. please can you have a look at it once more. I thinks its this line of code that causes the issue  
  //cars: Car[];

cars: Car;
  error = '';
  success = '';

 car = new Car('', 0);      Can you assist me further between thanks so far

Comment: I have also added car.ts and hope you can help me further. Thanks so far

Comment: I have also added <String> to my Post pathways as per this.http.post<string>(...  and its working now. Thank you so much at Nolan

Comment: No problem, jmarkatti let me know if you need anything else, sorry for late response.